# How called quotes of string litherals in lexical analysis?

Tags: lexical-analysis

In C-like languages, the **string litherals** are the arbitrary characters surrouned with quotes (e. g. `"example"`). But what is `"`? I know that it is **terminal**, or **therminal character**, but is should be some specifin

Comment: what are you asking about? a clearer explanation of your confusion/problem would help others to give you better answers.

Comment: [This link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-special-symbols-in-c-language) provides some of the 'special symbols' (reserved) of C. These are generally referred as 'reserved symbols' or 'special symbols'. Arigato (thank you).

Comment: @Mubin, I am sorry for the unclear question.  Had I failed to express by"How called quotes of string litherals in lexical analysis?" what I need to know single term's name?

Comment: @jsN00b, thank you for the comment. According your explanations, I suppose, it will be the "quote special symbol"... Or maybe "string litheral delimiter".

Comment: I feel 'string-literal delimiter' is good way to describe. Please, however, note that it may be applied for both quotation `'` as well as double-quotation `"` symbols.